# Fluent Validation: Changing control style on error

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

I'm using Fluent Validation in my ASP.NET MVC application. I need to change the CSS class of the control when there's an error. Please see my code below.

```
using FluentValidation;
using Hrms.Framework.Common;
using Hrms.Web.Models;

namespace Hrms.Web.InputValidators
{
    public class AnnouncementValidator : AbstractValidator<AnnouncementModel>
    {
        public AnnouncementValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(a => a.Title).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Announcement Title is required");
            RuleFor(a => a.Title).MaximumLength(50).WithMessage(string.Format("Announcement Title should be 50 characters or less", 50));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code I have in the view (HTML)

```
@model Hrms.Web.Models.AnnouncementModel

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Application.cshtml";    
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", "Announcement", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    OnFailure = "saveFailed",
    OnSuccess = "saveSucc",    
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "result"
}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div id="result"></div>
    <label>@Resources.Organization.Announcement.Title</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title, new { maxlength = @GlobalConstants.AnnouncementTitleMaxLength })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, null, new { @class = "errVal" })

    <input type="submit" value="Save">
}

@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#SendingDate").datepicker();
        });

        function saveSucc(m) {
            $("#Title").val("");
            $("#Body").val("");
            $("#SendingDate").val("");            
        }

        function saveFailed() {
            alert("saveFailed");
        }
    </script>
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated

When I tried to edit this post, it showed an error saying that I cannot edit this post because it is mostly code, it asked me to add more details. And because there are no more details in my mind to add, I decided to add this text. I'm sorry...

Comment: Please share the View.

Comment: I guess you are using the ValidationMessageFor to show the errors, in the third parameter you can set htmlAttributes.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I've added the view code. Bruno Quintella, the third parameter is dedicated for the style of the text, but what I'm looking for is to change the style of the control itself